# Powershell reporting wrong variable value

Tags: powershell, variables

new to stackoverflow. Have been a lurker for years but now need help. I am writing a simple script for an MSP to detect for a base set of applications and if not installed to run the chocolatey install command for that app. When I run this in ISE as an admin it reports back true for all the variable values even if it is not true. If I run just the test-path and tell it to write-host the value it is correct. But when ran all together it always comes back True. Can someone help investigate for me?

```
#Are programs installed?

    $a = Test-Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" IF ($a = "True") {Write-Host "7-zip is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "7-zip is not installed, install command sent" choco install 7zip -y}

    $b = Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" IF ($b = "True") {Write-Host "Firefox is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Firefox is not installed, install command sent"}

    $c = Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC" IF ($c = "True") {Write-Host "Adobe Reader is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Adobe Reader is not installed, install command sent"}

    $d = Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome" IF ($d = "True") {Write-Host "Chrome is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Chrome is not installed, install command sent"}
```

Comment: = is PowerShell's assignment operator.  Check for equality with -eq.

Comment: Also, $true is the boolean true value, not "True".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues,

```
IF ($a = "True")
```

You cant use an `=` equals, you must use a `-eq`. Also, "True" is a `String` containing 4 characters, the `boolean` values for True and False are `$true` and `$false`, so your code becomes:

```
    IF ($a -eq $true)
```

But you can simplify this further:

```
    IF ($a)
```

Below is how i would write this logic:

```
if(-not (Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip")){
    Write-Host "Installing 7-Zip...";
    # do stuff ... 
}else{
    Write-Host "7-Zip already installed";
}
```

(Like in Mathematics you start from the innermost parentheses and work outwards, in this case `Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"` first - which in my case returns `$true`. The `-not()` negates the result of the expression in the parentheses `(` `)` changing it to `$false`).

Given how you plan to use it, you should probably wrap it up inside a function so you can write the logic once and re-use it without duplicating the code such as:

```
#Simple function
function InstallIfNessersary([String] $installDir, [String] $chocoPackage){
    if(-not (Test-Path -Path $installDir)){
        Write-Host "Installing Package $chocoPackage...";
        #Do stuff with $chocoPackage
    }else{
        Write-Host "7-Zip already installed";
    }
}

#Call the function for each app
InstallIfNessersary -installDir "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" -chocoPackage 7zip
InstallIfNessersary -installDir "C:\Program Files\X" -chocoPackage X
InstallIfNessersary -installDir "C:\Program Files\Y" -chocoPackage Y
```

Which on my PC outputs:

```
7-Zip already installed
Installing Package X...
Installing Package Y...
```

Comment: I didn't mean to steal your answer as you are absolutely correct. I am a web server pseudo coder so thanks for not tearing me down as I learn PowerShell.

Comment: Good answer, but please use `-not (...)`, not `-not(...)`, as the latter suggests _method_ syntax, which is not applicable to any PowerShell _operators_.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter into the console the code exactly like it is in the question? If so, then it isn't correct syntax. The `if` statements need to be on a new line, or have `;` separating them from the `Test-path` statement:

```
$a = Test-Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
IF ($a = "True") {Write-Host "7-zip is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "7-zip is not installed, install command sent" choco install 7zip -y}

$b = Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
IF ($b = "True") {Write-Host "Firefox is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Firefox is not installed, install command sent"}

$c = Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC"
IF ($c = "True") {Write-Host "Adobe Reader is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Adobe Reader is not installed, install command sent"}

$d = Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome"
IF ($d = "True") {Write-Host "Chrome is installed"} ELSE {Write-Host "Chrome is not installed, install command sent"}
```

When trying to figure out when something is not working, proper formatting can help, especially when copy pasting code into a window. If everything still is reporting 'True' check to see if your console has those variables set to `true` already

Answer (score 0):

I was setting my variable to true and not checking for the value. Changed = to -eq for if statement and it runs fine now.